# ExtJs4: Panel : SQL SyntaxHighlighter: No scrollbars/wrapping of lines

Tags: extjs4, syntax-highlighting, syntaxhighlighter, ext-panel

I am using an ExtJs Panel to display an SQL query on the screen. 
For highlighting the query I am using SyntaxHighlighter.

Problem: I am not getting scrollbars in the panel even after setting `"autoScroll: true"` for the panel.

I have tried the following:

Earlier Highlighter Code:

```
'<pre class="brush: sql">' + sqlOutput + '</pre>'
```

Thing I tried:

```
'<pre class="brush: sql;wrap-lines: false">' + sqlOutput + '</pre>';
```

But no success.
Can anyone help me with this.

**UPDATE**

I am able to get a vertical scrollbar in Chrome but no horizontal scrollbar

This is how it looks:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may either specify a maxWidth on the panel (quick n' dirty solution) or add a fixed-width layout specification in the parent container of the panel.